# Fill Between Missbehaviour?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

everyone! I am trying to color with intense red the triangular area between the black line and the two red lines that is currently in light red (in the right). After reading the corresponding section of the manual and some questions posted in this site, I more or less understand how the feature "fillbetween" works, but I still cannot get exactly what I want. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or nor properly understanding? This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,skip=0pt,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=black,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/xlabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel}},/pgfplots/ylabel near ticks/.style={/pgfplots/every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Pay-off Area of the Infinitely Repeated Game A}
\label{Pay-off Area of the Infinitely Repeated Game A II}
\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmax=5,
xmin=0,
ymax=5,
ymin=0,
extra tick style={grid=major},
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={$P_1$'s utility (pay-offs)},
ylabel={$P_2$'s utility (pay-offs)},
xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
ytick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.25)},anchor=north}, 
width=7cm,
height=7cm
]
\addplot[thick, black, no markers, fill=red, fill opacity=0.30, name path=A] coordinates {
(5, 1)
(4, 4)
(1, 5)
(2, 2)
(5, 1)
};
\addlegendentry{Feasible Pay-off Area of both Players};
\addplot +[mark=none, red, thick, name path=B] coordinates {(2, 0) (2, 5)};
\addplot +[mark=none, red, thick, name path=C] coordinates {(0, 2) (5, 2)};
\addplot +[mark=none, gray, ultra thin, name path=D] coordinates {(4, 0) (4, 5)};
\addplot +[mark=none, gray, ultra thin, name path=E] coordinates {(0, 4) (5, 4)};
\addlegendentry{Min-Max Pay-off Area of both Players};
\addplot +[fill=red, fill opacity=0.40] fill between[of=B and D, soft clip={domain=4:2, domain y=2:4}];
\addplot +[fill=red, fill opacity=0.40] fill between[of=E and A, soft clip={domain=2:4}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output I obtain:

[image]

The change that I need is to change the color of the left light red triangle, to make it look dark red and not light. I know that the tools are already there, but I have tried all feasible combinations and there is no way to obtain what I need. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it. The trick is to use the `split` key and then to fill the second segment using `every segment no 1/.style` (the index starts with 0).

Here is the code now only containing the relevant parts for the solution.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmax=5,
            xmin=0,
            ymax=5,
            ymin=0,
            width=7cm,
            height=7cm,
            no markers,
        ]
            \addplot [
                thick,
                black,
                fill=red,
                fill opacity=0.30,
                name path=A,
            ] coordinates {
                (5, 1)
                (4, 4)
                (1, 5)
                (2, 2)
            }
                -- cycle
            ;
            \addplot+ [
                red,
                thick,
                name path=B,
            ] coordinates {(2, 0) (2, 5)};

            \addplot+ [
                fill=none,
            ] fill between [
                of=A and B,
                split,
                every segment no 1/.style={
                    fill=green,
                },
            ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

---

**Edit:**

Here is again the solution, but now modified in that way that you can see, where the intersections are found and to how many segments this should result in.

This most probably doesn't work as you expect, but can be explained by the [section 5.7.8 item 3 on page 427 of the `pgfplots` manual v1.13](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=427)

That this works for "normal" cases you can try yourself with one of the examples given in the manual.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        patterns,
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xmax=5,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
            clip=false,
        ]
            \addplot [
                thick,
                black,
                name path=A,
            ] coordinates {
                (5, 1)
                (4, 4)
                (1, 5)
                (2, 2)
            }
                node [at start,label={right:start\,=\,end}] (start) {}
                -- cycle
            ;
            \addplot [
                red,
                thick,
                name path=B,
            ] coordinates {(2, 0) (2, 5)};

            % fill all segments with the checkerboard pattern
            % from this can be seen, that there should be 3 segments (0,1,2)
            \addplot [
                pattern=checkerboard,
                pattern color=blue!50,
            ] fill between [
                of=A and B,
            ];
            % now we try to fill them separately
            \addplot [
                fill=none,
            ] fill between [
                of=A and B,
                split,
                % works
                every segment no 0/.style={
                    fill=red!50,
                    opacity=0.5,
                },
                % works
                every segment no 1/.style={
                    fill=green!50,
                    opacity=0.5,
                },
                % doesn't work
                % this is most probably because path A intersects with itself;
                % see section 5.7.8 «Pitfalls and Limitations» on page 427
                % in the manual v1.13
%                every segment no 2/.style={% <-- equivalent to next line
                every last segment/.style={
                    fill=yellow!50,
                },
            ];

            % show the intersections of the pathes which show together with
            % the start/end point(s) the beginning/end of the segments
            \draw [
                name intersections={
                    of=A and B,
                    name=i,
                    total=\t,
                },
                black,
                every node/.style={
                    above left,
                    black,
                    opacity=1,
                }
            ]
            \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{
                (i-\s) circle (2pt) node {\footnotesize\s}
            };

        \end{axis}
            \fill [red,radius=2pt] (start) circle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I complied your code and it works fine, generating the expected figure. However, I have been using the commands you suggested and I have reading the corresponding manual again, but I still do not get the result I need. Basically, I am afraid I still do not understand how the commands you provided work. If possible, could you please provide further help?

Comment: @Héctor, I am not totally sure what you expect me to answer now. Applying my suggested code to your (full) code also works fine for me. So was that just a dummy picture and you _real_ picture has another structure?  Or do you mean I should explain in more detail how the `fillbeween` library is working?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After some hours of work, I managed to obtained the output I needed. However, I discover a very simple way to do it that did not require to use the split function. In any case, I consider the question to be answered.